# How to wait tasks with conditions?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have some tasks which return a bool. I just want wait until when any task returns True firstly. is it possible ?

My first idea was to use a CancellationTokenSource but it was not a good idea because of it throws an exception when I call the Task.WaitAll method.

The second option is to use a bool I pass in reference and if it's true, return directly. it works but it's not performant :

```
bool isFound = false;
Task<bool> t0 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramA, paramB, ref isFound));
Task<bool> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramC, paramD, ref isFound));
Task<bool> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramE, paramF, ref isFound));
Task<bool> t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramG, paramH, ref isFound));

Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t0, t1, t2, t3, t4 });
return t0.Result | t1.Result | t2.Result | t3.Result | t4.Result;
```

and in the method :

```
 private static bool Find(int[,] m1, int[,] m2, ref bool isFound)
 {
      if (isFound)
           return false;

      // Do work...
 }
```

EDIT :

As the answer preconized, I use a `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` now :

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
Task<bool> t0 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramA, paramB);
Task<bool> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramC, paramD);
Task<bool> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramE, paramF);
Task<bool> t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramG, paramH);

t0.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t0.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t0.Result);
});

t1.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t1.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t1.Result);
});

t2.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t2.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t2.Result);
});

t3.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t3.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t3.Result);
});

t4.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t4.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t4.Result);
});

tcs.Task.Wait();
return tcs.Task.Result;
```

In this case, when all tasks return false, nothing is noticed and it's normal. However I don't know how to use the `WhenAll` method. I tried to add this :

```
tcs.Task.Wait();
Task tr = Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { t0, t1, t2, t3, t4 });

if (tr.IsCompleted)
    return false;
else
    return tcs.Task.Result;
```

But it does not work :(

Comment: Don't you want to use WaitAny rather than WaitAll? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to create a `TaskCompletionSource` of whatever type you want (to identify the result, if that's required). Then add a continuation to each of the tasks, calling [`TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449176.aspx) if the result is true.

Then just wait on the `TaskCompletionSource.Task`. It avoids you having to call [`Task.WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235627) repeatedly, checking for results etc.

The tricky bit is noticing when *all* tasks have returned false... in .NET 4.5 this would be reasonably easy, by creating another task via [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - then you'd just wait for the first of `{ success, all failed }` to complete.

Comment: It works fine when a task return true. But I'm trying to deal with Task.WhenAll and nothing appears to be noticed...

Comment: @Florian: So are you using .NET 4.5? It may be worth either updating this question or starting a new one for the `WhenAll` case. Fundamentally you're after "the first of { any that returns true, all have returned }" to occur, right?

Comment: Yes I'm using .Net 4.5. I think I Misusing .WhenAll method. I'll update the question

Answer (score 3):

You need [`WaitHandle.WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx). At the very beginning you set up a `WaitHandle[]`, each one waits a `Task`, when the task is successfully executed (and get `true` as a result as you expected), you signal the corresponding `WaitHandle`.

Comment: Yes - I guess he actually want `WaitAny` but it's not clear what he trying to do. In first question he just XORed the answers from all of them. In second iteration he set single result in `TrySetResult` without any XOR. So I guess both answers `WhenAll` and `WhenAny` are good

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which would pretty much make your `isFound` property redundant e.g.

```
private static ManualResetEvent found = new ManualResetEvent(false);
...

Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramA, paramB));     
Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramC, paramD));     
Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramE, paramF));     
Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramG, paramH));  

var result = found.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); // wait with timeout of 10 secs

// do something with result

...
private static bool Find(int[,] m1, int[,] m2)          
{          
    if (found.WaitOne(0)) // check whether MSE has already been set
        return false;        

    // Do work...
    found.Set();
}
```