# How to use Task.WhenAll properly

Tags: c#, task, async-await

Following to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824755/how-to-wait-tasks-with-conditions/11824832#11824832) (and its answer) I want to use TaskCompletionSource and `Task.WhenAll` to wait until when any task returns True firstly. So I wrote this :

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
Task<bool> t0 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramA, paramB);
Task<bool> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramC, paramD);
Task<bool> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramE, paramF);
Task<bool> t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(paramG, paramH);

t0.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t0.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t0.Result);
});

t1.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t1.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t1.Result);
});

t2.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t2.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t2.Result);
});

t3.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t3.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t3.Result);
});

t4.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (t4.Result)
        tcs.TrySetResult(t4.Result);
});

tcs.Task.Wait();
return tcs.Task.Result;
```

it works fine when any task returns `true` but, as noticed in the previously answer :

> The tricky bit is noticing when all tasks have returned false... in
>   .NET 4.5 this would be reasonably easy, by creating another task via
>   Task.WhenAll

So I tried to play with `Task.WhenAll` but it I don't want to use it correctly...
I tried something like that :

```
tcs.Task.Wait(); // stays block here when all tasks return false
Task tr = Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { t0, t1, t2, t3, t4 });

if (tr.IsCompleted)
   return false;
else
return tcs.Task.Result;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: How to use Task.WhenAll to get a result even if all tasks return false ?

Answer (score 5):

You want to wait until one of the two tasks you have finished, that's what [`Task.WaitAny()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany) is for:

```
Task tr = Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { t0, t1, t2, t3, t4 });
Task.WaitAny(tcs.Task, tr);

if (tcs.Task.IsCompleted)
    return tcs.Task.Result;

return false;
```

This also fixes a race condition in your code: `tr.IsCompleted` could be `true`, even if some task returned `true`, because all of the tasks could finish at the same time.

As an alternative, you could use [`Task.WhenAny()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany%28v=vs.110%29), if you didn't want to block.

But since you are using .Net 4.5 you might as well use `await` together with [`Interleaved()` method, which orders the tasks as they complete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx):

```
async Task<bool> AnyTrue(IEnumerable<Task<bool>> tasks)
{
    foreach(var bucket in Interleaved(tasks))
    {
        if (await await bucket)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To check the result when it is `false` you can use

```
if (!task.Result)
{ 
    // Do stuff...
}
```

this will check if the boolean result was false. To be more complete you could do something like

```
asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Check task status.
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncTask.Result)
            {
                // returned true.
            }
            else
            {
                // returned false
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.