# Wait all tasks with some conditions

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I am writing some complex tasks and I can't do success to solve the problem.

1. I open some tasks for searching some data asynchronously.
2. At the end I wait for all tasks.
3. I want to run on all the data and does not stop the tasks until they all finish.
   But, when one of the tasks finds some relevant data, I want to continue with the code that is after the wait all tasks, but at the same time, I want to continue searching with my tasks (until all the data will be read).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824755/how-to-wait-tasks-with-conditions) I found a way how to continue the code after the wait all if one of the tasks finds the data, the problem is that it also stops all tasks from running.

Here is my code (this  is just code for demonstration of the problem).

```
private static void RunTasks()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Task<bool> t0 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(1, 2));
    Task<bool> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(4, 7));
    Task<bool> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(13, 14));

    t0.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        if (t0.Result)
            tcs.TrySetResult(t0.Result);
    });

    t1.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        if (t1.Result)
            tcs.TrySetResult(t1.Result);
    });

    t2.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        if (t2.Result)
            tcs.TrySetResult(t2.Result);
    });

    tcs.Task.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Found");
    ContinueWork(); //Runs after at least one data found or when all tasks finish.
}

//Just for demonstration...
private static bool Find(int a, int b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("a: " + a + " b: " + b);
    return a == 4 && b == 7 ? true : false;
}
```

How can I write it so that when some data is found it will continue to ContinueWork method and also will continue with reading the data with the tasks?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You say this code stops executing tasks as soon as you set the result? I can't reproduce the issue. It executes all the three tasks. Am I missing something?

Comment: if i understood you correctly maybe you need to create an array of tasks with those 3 tasks then call Task.WhenAny passing the array.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The tasks stops when I find one result. But I don't want it.

Comment: @terrybozzio I thought about WhenAny but the problem is that WhenAny will stop all tasks when the find returns true. Or am I wrong?

Comment: it will wait in "that spot" until the first result comes then it continues from that spot and the tasks will go all to the end.

Comment: @terrybozzio When you say that the tasks will go all to the end you mean that the tasks will continue until they all finish their run?

Comment: @terrybozzio That's good. That's seems what I need. Could you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the cleanest way but it will serve your purposes:

```
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            Task<bool>[] tasks = new Task<bool>[3];
            tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(1, 2));
            tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(4, 7));
            tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => Find(13, 14));

            tasks[0].ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                if (tasks[0].Result)
                    tcs.TrySetResult(tasks[0].Result);
            });

            tasks[1].ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                if (tasks[1].Result)
                    tcs.TrySetResult(tasks[1].Result);
            });

            tasks[2].ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                if (tasks[2].Result)
                    tcs.TrySetResult(tasks[2].Result);
            });

            Task.WaitAny(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Found");
            ContinueWork();
```