# How to stop execution of Tasks left when I get certain result from method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

So I'm just starting to work with `Task Parallel Library` and I'm starting to see imrpovement in my code execution time. Right now I'm starting three methods in parallel each of them returning `true` or `false` to determine if a certain user has some product to his profile:

```
                List<bool> hasProducts = new List<bool>();

                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>() {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                        hasProducts.Add(HasDeposits(clientId));
                    }),
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                        hasProducts.Add(HasAccounts(clientId));
                    }),
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                        hasProducts.Add(HasBankSafes(clientId));
                    })

                };
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

                client.hasProducts = hasProducts.Where(p => p == true).Any();
```

This works fine and much faster than executing the methods in a non parallel way. However in my current scenario what I really want to know (as you can see from this part - `hasProducts.Where(p => p == true).Any();`) is not what product the client have or how many. All that I careis if the user has `Any` product to his name or not. So except the case when the user doesn't have any product associated with him I think I will get best performance if I stop execution at the moment a method return true as result.

That being said, what I want to as is, how can I change this code so that it stops execution if at any point, any of the methods return true, and how can I determine that a method has returned `true` so I cann assign it to the  `client.hasProducts` value or all methods has finished execution and ll of them returned false?

Comment: pass in a cancellation token & use Task.Any instead of WaitAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824755/how-to-wait-tasks-with-conditions), i guess is similar to your case which also returns true on success. It uses the TaskCompletionSource.

One other solution is to use the cancellation token as mentioned by Lee Gary, which [throws an OperationCanceledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx)